# What is the correct syntax for this JS loop including a lot of document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript

I am making a tournament table on HTML and JS. I have a couple of hundred of « match boxes » to which I want to assign a range of different datas (such as a logo/flag, name of the team, score and more).

How could I write a loop that would execute the following potential thousands of lines :

```
document.getElementById("matchBox1_team1").innerHTML = teams[1].name;
document.getElementById("matchBox1_flag1").innerHTML = teams[1].flag;
document.getElementById("matchBox1_team2").innerHTML = teams[2].name;
document.getElementById("matchBox1_flag2").innerHTML = teams[2].flag;
document.getElementById("matchBox2_team1").innerHTML = teams[3].name;
document.getElementById("matchBox2_flag1").innerHTML = teams[3].flag;
document.getElementById("matchBox2_team2").innerHTML = teams[4].name;
document.getElementById("matchBox2_flag2").innerHTML = teams[4].flag;
```

etc…

something like this but I havent got the syntax right :

```
var j=1;
for (i=0;i<1000;i+=2){
    document.getElementById("matchBox("j")_team1").innerHTML = teams[i].name;
    document.getElementById("matchBox("j")_flag1").innerHTML = teams[i].flag;
    document.getElementById("matchBox("j")_team2").innerHTML = teams[i+1].name;
    document.getElementById("matchBox("j")_flag2").innerHTML = teams[i+1].flag;
    j++}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Change `"matchBox("j")_team1"` to `"matchBox" + j + "_team1"`

Comment: `\`matchBox${j}_team1\``, or the old `'matchBox' + j + '_team1'`, but string concatenation should really be part of any basic js tutorial.

Comment: Your initial code has wrong numbering.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your method of retrieving data. If you are using ajax then create table rows with js and append those rows to the table so you will only have to get only a single element.

```
var matchesTable = document.getElementById('matches');

function addMatch(name,flag){
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    var nameColumn = document.createElement('th');
    nameColumn.innerText = name;

    var flagColumn = document.createElement('th');
    flagColumn.innerText = flag;

    row.append(nameColumn);
    row.append(flagColumn);

    matchesTable.append(row);
}
```

Wherever you get that data just call addMatch function and pass all the details as parameters and create th elements for all those details and append to that table.

Else you will need thousands of those rows already created for you to get them and then add those details.

Answer (score 0):

Using `id` attributes with sequential numbers is a code smell: it is bad practice. Instead you should use classes where their sequence follows from their natural order in the DOM.

For instance:

```js
let teams = [
  { name: "New York Knicks", flag: "flagged" },
  { name: "Toronto Raptors", flag: "cleared" },
  { name: "Sacramento Kings", flag: "cleared" },
  { name: "Miami Hear", flag: "pending" }
];

let teamElems = document.querySelectorAll(".matchBox .team");
let flagElems = document.querySelectorAll(".matchBox .flag");

teams.forEach(({name, flag}, i) => { 
  teamElems[i].textContent = name;
  flagElems[i].textContent = flag;
});
```

```css
.matchBox { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<div class="matchBox">
    <div class="team"></div>
    <div class="flag"></div>
</div>
<div class="matchBox">
    <div class="team"></div>
    <div class="flag"></div>
</div>
<div class="matchBox">
    <div class="team"></div>
    <div class="flag"></div>
</div>
<div class="matchBox">
    <div class="team"></div>
    <div class="flag"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `appendChild` method into the for loop you have created.
Also one hint is you have to create the element (`createElement`) which you want to insert in the for loop and insert it in the table you have created using `appendChild`.
You can refer to syntax on [w3cschool](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp)